# Reducing the number of items in a Bootstrap 3 carousel for mobile

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm currently making a website in Bootstrap 3.0 with a carousel.

In mobile mode (xs) I have 4 items in the carousel, but when it gets to tablet size (sm or md) the client wants to drop this to just 2 items instead of 4.

Hiding the indicators is easy enough, you can use hidden-sm to get rid of 2 of the dots, and I've also added hidden-sm to the items themselves, but the JS that controls the carousel ignored the fact that the items are set to display: none, and it scrolls through them anyway.

Does anyone know of a way to get Bootstrap to ignore items at certain responsive breakpoints?

Comment: There is no built in way of doing this and it would require custom jQuery to skip the items. This is not a responsive design request, it's adaptive, and the way I do this is server side with a mobile detect class and I load the html for different devices, so I load the desktop version if not mobile and else mobile. In pinch, since the images are loaded into cache, you can show one version for desktop and one version for mobile,  use the responsive utility classes

Comment: Thanks Christian, I took your advice, for this one, I've toggled between 2 different carousels at the 2 different break points, as I'm 99% sure the client will change this later anyway! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but needed to be able to dynamically change the number of slides. To keep it simple, I chose to base it on the visibility of the carousel indicators. I added the following to `bootstrap.js`, just after the variable declarations inside `Carousel.prototype.slide()`:

```
var $nextIndicator;
if (this.$indicators.length) {
  var iChildren = this.$indicators.children();
  var i=0; 
  while (($nextIndicator = $(iChildren[this.getItemIndex($next)])) && !$nextIndicator.is(':visible') && i<iChildren.length) {
    $next = $next[type]();
    if (!$next.length) {
      if (!this.options.wrap) return
      $next = this.$element.find('.item')[fallback]()
    }    
    i++; 
  }    
}
```

To remove slides I put the following in my own code:

```
$indicatorsToRemove.hide();
// don't leave user on a page that got removed:
if ($indicatorsToRemove.filter('.active').length) {
  $('#carousel').carousel('next');
}
```

To add them back:

```
$indicatorsToAdd.show();
```